# CS-Cart Menu in custom template

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

I am making a template in CS-Cart by including the needed tpl files directly into my html where needed. But what I'm not sure how to do is include the main menu.

eg.

```
{include file="common/search.tpl"}
```

I've created a custom menu, which currently contains two categories and two pages, and called it 'Top Nav'. How do I include this in my html template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but you'll still need to use the block manager.

You can create a block for your menu, and manually insert it by following the tutorial here: http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/29828-a-simple-way-to-add-any-content-on-any-place-on-template/

Though, as Alexander points out, it's not the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to start using the built-in block manager.
A block is a "widget" that can be put into an any place on the page using GUI at the administration panel. There is no separate template for that, blocks are being rendered dynamically - you can't just include it into your template.

So you should create a block that will render the menu you've created and position it on your page layout.

Check out the documentation to learn more: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/user_guide/look_and_feel/menus/index.html

Comment: In fact, if you're creating your own template, it should be either template of your own block or a template for the main content (which is also a block).

Comment: I was hoping to code the components into my html for header and footer for better design control and only use the block manager for the content area. The blocks for search/cart contents/login etc seem to work ok being manually inserted. But there is no obvious way to do the menu like this...